# Documentation for programming languages supported by IBM Db2?

Tags: db2

What programming languages are supported by Db2? I know it supports JavaScript and other latest languages. But this link is not up to date: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.gs.doc/doc/r0023434.html

Comment: There is a change version option on that page that refers to more current versions - i.e. Db2 11.1 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.gs.doc/doc/r0023434.html

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation, the IBM Db2 Knowledge Center, is a version selector. You referenced version 9.5 which is just old and unsupported since years.

Here is the section on [Application Development for Db2 Version 11](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.javascript.doc/doc/c0061582.html). In the table of contents on the left is a long list of programming languages with sections on how to install the drivers and with code samples.